# Jquery toggle just the p tags under the div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quick, simple question.
I have this function working at the moment ;

```
$("#menuopties").click(function(){
$("p").toggle();
});
```

However this toggles every p tag.
I just want to toggle the p tags which are under the div #menuopties (which has been clicked)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) them.

Comment: Under the #menuopties or inside them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current selector `"p"` will get all the elements of type `p` instead of getting the `p` within the current object. Use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendant of current element. you will get the source of event object using `$(this)`

```
$("#menuopties").click(function(){
   $(this).find("p").toggle();
});
```

You can use pass current object in context of the selector using [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

```
$("#menuopties").click(function(){
   $("p", this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, all the answers did work however yours was the most complete and did not simply solve it but also teach me something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('p').toggle();` to `$(this).children('p').toggle();`

`$(this)` refers to the current jQuery object (in this case wrapping the `#menuopties` DOM element), so running `.children()` allows you to filter its descendant elements by whatever selector you want (in this case `p`).

edit: as buzzsawddog pointed out, it's important to note `.children()` only returns the child elements a single level below in the DOM, so if your `p` tags are not immediate children of `#menuopties` you should use `.find()` instead.

Comment: Depending on the scope of his problem find() might be better than .children().  For example what if there is another div inside his div? or a span?

Comment: Good point.  I went with the most simple answer since he didn't provide any markup, but you're absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed the div containers other divs. However your answer was still usefull. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#menuopties").click(function(){
$(this).find("p").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, helped but I preferred an other solution with explanation !

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3 No issues :) my friend.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("p", this).toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks, helped but I preferred an other solution with explanation !

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#menuopties").click(function(){
    $(this).find("p").toggle();
});
```

hope that helped.

Comment: Helped and thank you but I preferred the first answer because it explains why. Thanks